# how decrease the number of variable in my function definition

Tags: python, function

The function `ELF_ReI` and `ELF_ReII` (are declared in the  beginning)) depends of `y` and `q`, but I will integrate in this variables. When I ask to `print phi_ind(v_cm, ro, z)`,  the program shows me this message, `TypeError: phi_ind() takes exactly 5 arguments (3 given).`

What I must to do?

```
def phi_ind(v_cm, ro, z):
    ELF_ReI = (2 / pi) * quad(ELF_Re, 0, y - 1E-5, args=(y, q))[0]
    ELF_ReII = (2 / pi) * quad(ELF_Re, y - 1E-5, np.inf, args=(y, q))[0]

    phi = (2 / pi * v_cm) * (1 / q) * jn(0, ro * sqrt(q ** 2 - (y / v_cm) ** 2)) * cos(y * z / v_cm) * (ELF_ReII)
    return integrate.dblquad(phi, 0, np.inf, lambda y: 0, lambda y: v_cm * y, args=(v_cm, ro, z))[0]
```

Comment: See the function declaration again.

Comment: The function *as you have written it here* has 3 arguments.  The function you are calling apparently has 5.  You have a spelling error or an indentation error or some other superficial problem like that.

Comment: Are you importing this code from another script? You are likely importing a different version of the module. Supposing the module name is `foo`, trying printing `foo.__file__` before calling the function. Also, delete any foo.pyc files lying around that may have old cruft. That usually isn't necessary unless you had some unlucky event where an old .pyc has a newer data than the new .py file (this is common if you revert a change in source repo).